# missing grubx64.efi

Tags: rhel, grub2, uefi

I rebooted my supermicro server and it failed to boot my linux disk.

Within the BIOS/EFI I can navigate to the one operating system disk and see the EFI partition and of all the `.efi` files listed but there is no `grubx64.efi`.

Which I believe is what you select, if you were to manually add your own boot option or if you were to manually boot from the EFI shell such as

```
fs0:\EFI\EFI\redhat\grubx64.efi
```

but I am missing this file.  How does one fix this?

This is on **RHEL 7.6**

Answer (score 1):

This occasionally happens on systems that don't save EFI variables correctly. (In particular, I've seen it with CentOS on VirtualBox a lot.) The workaround I use is `cp redhat/grubx64.efi BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` (after creating `BOOT/` if it doesn't already exist). If you're not on a single-boot system that you always want to boot into GRUB, then you'll have to fix it properly with `efibootmgr`, but note that if your EFI is broken, that fix won't last either.

Comment: As suggested in the other answer's comments, http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html might help wrap your head around this new crap.  Those articles helped me a lot to implement UEFI support in ALT Linux back then...

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly complicated process which I'm afraid I won't be able to detail all of the steps now. If required, I will be happy to do that later. All in all, following are the steps required:

1. Enter into recovery mode using RHEL boot disk.
2. Mount your system's `root`, `boot` and `EFI` partitions into a temporary directory tree such as `/tmp`, `/tmp/boot`, and `/tmp/boot/efi` respectively and then `chroot` there (eg `chroot /tmp`).
3. Make sure you are connected to internet. If not, connect using `nmtui` or some similar tool.
4. Install the packages `grub2-efi` and `shim` [[Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2#sec-grub2-reinstall_on_UEFI-Based_Machines)].
5. Rebuild `grub` by issuing `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`  [[Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2#sec-grub2-reinstall_on_UEFI-Based_Machines)].

Reboot your system. Verify that RHEL or the disk with EFI partition is selected as a boot option in BIOS and then try to boot your OS.

That should do it.

Comment: I booted rhel7.6 dvd, rescue mode, `chroot /mnt/sys` and I was able to do successfully do a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/efi/redhat/grub.cfg` however that did not recreate a `grubx64.efi`

Comment: `grub2-mkconfig` just creates the `grub.cfg` file. You need to install `grub2-efi` and `shim` packages (mentioned in step 4). The first package will install `grubx64.efi` and the second one will install `shimx64.efi`. Only after installing those packages, use `grub2-mkconfig` to regenerate your `grub.cfg` file.

Comment: Should have been `grub2-install` with no arguments (or `grub-install` if it's named that way) as it will also install the binary itsel and call `efibootmgr` to create a NVRAM entry for it.
I'd suggest this excellent intro: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: I am not sure how `grub2-install` can be useful in creating the `grubx64.efi` file which is being provided by another package, ie, `grub2-efi` (and which seems to be missing for the OP). Additionally for RHEL I would trust the official documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-reinstalling_grub_2#sec-grub2-reinstall_on_BIOS-Based_Machines which clearly states that `grub2-install` is needed only for BIOS based systems and is not mentioned in the UEFI machines section.